# DBT - use DBT modeling to insert rows in a table like date dimension table in Azure Synapse

Tags: insert-update, dbt, azure-synapse, fishtown-analytics

I need reference to inserting rows in a table using DBT models. Sample example that can be considered is a date dimension table, where we want to insert rows for next years.

Comment: DBT's Incremental Models might work for your use case: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models/

Answer (score 4):

dbt is built to [handle the inserts for you](https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/insert-records) since it generally works as a transformation layer on data already in your warehouse.

As an example of how to build a date dimension table, the gitlab data team have a public repo which includes an example of how to build that using the [dbt-utils](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils) package macro for a [date spine](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/date_spine.sql)

The simplest version would just be:

`date_dim.sql`

```
WITH date_spine AS (

  {{ dbt_utils.date_spine(
      start_date="to_date('01/01/2000', 'mm/dd/yyyy')",
      datepart="day",
      end_date="to_date('12/01/2050', 'mm/dd/yyyy')"
     )
  }}

)

select * from date_spine
```

[image]

And the link to the gitlab example:

[date_details_source.sql](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-data/analytics/-/blob/master/transform/snowflake-dbt/models/sources/date/date_details_source.sql)

```
WITH date_spine AS (

  {{ dbt_utils.date_spine(
      start_date="to_date('11/01/2009', 'mm/dd/yyyy')",
      datepart="day",
      end_date="dateadd(year, 40, current_date)"
     )
  }}

), calculated as (

    SELECT
      date_day,
      date_day                                                                                AS date_actual,

      DAYNAME(date_day)                                                                       AS day_name,

      DATE_PART('month', date_day)                                                            AS month_actual,
      DATE_PART('year', date_day)                                                             AS year_actual,
      DATE_PART(quarter, date_day)                                                            AS quarter_actual,

      DATE_PART(dayofweek, date_day) + 1                                                      AS day_of_week,
      CASE WHEN day_name = 'Sun' THEN date_day
        ELSE DATEADD('day', -1, DATE_TRUNC('week', date_day)) END                             AS first_day_of_week,

      CASE WHEN day_name = 'Sun' THEN WEEK(date_day) + 1
        ELSE WEEK(date_day) END                                                               AS week_of_year_temp, --remove this column

      CASE WHEN day_name = 'Sun' AND LEAD(week_of_year_temp) OVER (ORDER BY date_day) = '1'
        THEN '1'
        ELSE week_of_year_temp END                                                            AS week_of_year,

      DATE_PART('day', date_day)                                                              AS day_of_month,

      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual, quarter_actual ORDER BY date_day)          AS day_of_quarter,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual ORDER BY date_day)                          AS day_of_year,

      CASE WHEN month_actual < 2
        THEN year_actual
        ELSE (year_actual+1) END                                                              AS fiscal_year,
      CASE WHEN month_actual < 2 THEN '4'
        WHEN month_actual < 5 THEN '1'
        WHEN month_actual < 8 THEN '2'
        WHEN month_actual < 11 THEN '3'
        ELSE '4' END                                                                          AS fiscal_quarter,

      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year, fiscal_quarter ORDER BY date_day)          AS day_of_fiscal_quarter,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year ORDER BY date_day)                          AS day_of_fiscal_year,

      TO_CHAR(date_day, 'MMMM')                                                               AS month_name,

      TRUNC(date_day, 'Month')                                                                AS first_day_of_month,
      LAST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual, month_actual ORDER BY date_day)    AS last_day_of_month,

      FIRST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual ORDER BY date_day)                 AS first_day_of_year,
      LAST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual ORDER BY date_day)                  AS last_day_of_year,

      FIRST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual, quarter_actual ORDER BY date_day) AS first_day_of_quarter,
      LAST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year_actual, quarter_actual ORDER BY date_day)  AS last_day_of_quarter,

      FIRST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year, fiscal_quarter ORDER BY date_day) AS first_day_of_fiscal_quarter,
      LAST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year, fiscal_quarter ORDER BY date_day)  AS last_day_of_fiscal_quarter,

      FIRST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year ORDER BY date_day)                 AS first_day_of_fiscal_year,
      LAST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year ORDER BY date_day)                  AS last_day_of_fiscal_year,

      DATEDIFF('week', first_day_of_fiscal_year, date_actual) +1                              AS week_of_fiscal_year,

      CASE WHEN EXTRACT('month', date_day) = 1 THEN 12
        ELSE EXTRACT('month', date_day) - 1 END                                               AS month_of_fiscal_year,

      LAST_VALUE(date_day) OVER (PARTITION BY first_day_of_week ORDER BY date_day)            AS last_day_of_week,

      (year_actual || '-Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_day))                                 AS quarter_name,

      (fiscal_year || '-' || DECODE(fiscal_quarter,
        1, 'Q1',
        2, 'Q2',
        3, 'Q3',
        4, 'Q4'))                                                                             AS fiscal_quarter_name,
      ('FY' || SUBSTR(fiscal_quarter_name, 3, 7))                                             AS fiscal_quarter_name_fy,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY fiscal_quarter_name)                                        AS fiscal_quarter_number_absolute,
      fiscal_year || '-' || MONTHNAME(date_day)                                               AS fiscal_month_name,
      ('FY' || SUBSTR(fiscal_month_name, 3, 8))                                               AS fiscal_month_name_fy,

      (CASE WHEN MONTH(date_day) = 1 AND DAYOFMONTH(date_day) = 1 THEN 'New Year''s Day'
        WHEN MONTH(date_day) = 12 AND DAYOFMONTH(date_day) = 25 THEN 'Christmas Day'
        WHEN MONTH(date_day) = 12 AND DAYOFMONTH(date_day) = 26 THEN 'Boxing Day'
        ELSE NULL END)::VARCHAR                                                               AS holiday_desc,
      (CASE WHEN HOLIDAY_DESC IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1 END)::BOOLEAN                                                                  AS is_holiday,
      DATE_TRUNC('month', last_day_of_fiscal_quarter)                                         AS last_month_of_fiscal_quarter,
      IFF(DATE_TRUNC('month', last_day_of_fiscal_quarter) = date_actual, TRUE, FALSE)         AS is_first_day_of_last_month_of_fiscal_quarter,
      DATE_TRUNC('month', last_day_of_fiscal_year)                                            AS last_month_of_fiscal_year,
      IFF(DATE_TRUNC('month', last_day_of_fiscal_year) = date_actual, TRUE, FALSE)            AS is_first_day_of_last_month_of_fiscal_year,
      DATEADD('day',7,DATEADD('month',1,first_day_of_month))                                  AS snapshot_date_fpa,
      DATEADD('day',44,DATEADD('month',1,first_day_of_month))                                 AS snapshot_date_billings

    FROM date_spine

), final AS (

    SELECT
      date_day,
      date_actual,
      day_name,
      month_actual,
      year_actual,
      quarter_actual,
      day_of_week,
      first_day_of_week,
      week_of_year,
      day_of_month,
      day_of_quarter,
      day_of_year,
      fiscal_year,
      fiscal_quarter,
      day_of_fiscal_quarter,
      day_of_fiscal_year,
      month_name,
      first_day_of_month,
      last_day_of_month,
      first_day_of_year,
      last_day_of_year,
      first_day_of_quarter,
      last_day_of_quarter,
      first_day_of_fiscal_quarter,
      last_day_of_fiscal_quarter,
      first_day_of_fiscal_year,
      last_day_of_fiscal_year,
      week_of_fiscal_year,
      month_of_fiscal_year,
      last_day_of_week,
      quarter_name,
      fiscal_quarter_name,
      fiscal_quarter_name_fy,
      fiscal_quarter_number_absolute,
      fiscal_month_name,
      fiscal_month_name_fy,
      holiday_desc,
      is_holiday,
      last_month_of_fiscal_quarter,
      is_first_day_of_last_month_of_fiscal_quarter,
      last_month_of_fiscal_year,
      is_first_day_of_last_month_of_fiscal_year,
      snapshot_date_fpa,
      snapshot_date_billings
    FROM calculated

)
```

** I believe the gitlab team uses Snowflake so if you're using another platform, you may need to change a few functions **

Comment: This solution is not working for Azure synapse analytics. Do you have any way of implementing the same in Azure Synapse.